# How to install windows services written in .Net with an installer package?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installation, installutil

I followed thoroughly the Microsoft [Tutorial: Create a Windows service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer). In particular, I saw [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#to-add-startup-parameters):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new MyNewService(args)
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

With the corresponding `ProjectInstaller`, also described in the tutorial, I was able to successfully install the service in the way described in the tutorial with `installutil`.

Now, the above code suggests that I can install an array of services with that program. For example, I've built up several services, and come up with code of the following kind:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new Service1(args),
        new Service2(args),
        new Service3(args),
        new Service4(args)
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Again, with the corresponding `ProjectInstaller`, installing those 4 services with `installutil` is fine. I get my services installed and I can even run them.

However, I was not able to find a way to pack this into an installer package. [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2019#create-an-installer-package-windows-desktop) mentions ClickOnce, WiX, and InstallShield package installers. In my development team, we use [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/). None of those installer packages seem to show in their documentation how to install services with the above 4-services `Main` program. Every time, I see how to install one single service at a time. I could for example write one of the above `Main` program for each of my services and pack those programs in my installer package.

Is it possible? How? I don't really want to create one visual studio project for each of my services just to install them. What possibilities do I have if I can't make it happen with the above array of services?

Comment: IIRC, you can reproduce the same with `installutil` logic in wix, or even call `installutil` during msi installation, created using wix. Which installer have you tried already?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused by your question. Are you wanting to do this using only Advanced Installer or are you open to using WiX?

Comment: I too was struggling with similar issues with winservices until I discovered topShelf (https://www.nuget.org/packages/TopShelf). All of a sudden winservices got super easy to create, test and deploy as you only create regular console applications and install them by command line parameters to the console app itself. Maybe this can be an alternative for you too? Good luck.

Comment: I have tried WiX until I learned that in my team we only use Advanced Installer.

Comment: I will try and ask to use topshelf. That seems to be a pretty nice tool. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use a setup project that includes all the services to be installed.
But you need to install the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project plugin (box icon)
this is a guide that could help you: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b7531b/create-simple-window-service-and-setup-project-with-installa/
Maybe when you add custom action on the setup project you can add more services to include in the setup file.